# Avoid NaN and Inf when dividing in R (using within formula)

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a column to my data set in R with the Within formula.

Data set name: Full_Stats

Objective: Add Minutespergoal column using within formula

Formula

```
Full_Stats2<-within(Full_Stats, 
                  {Minutespergoal<-Minutes_played/Goal })
```

The formula works fine, but I'd like to avoid having NaN and Inf in the result. How could I fix this?

Please let me know if any question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` occurs by dividing zero by zero, and infinity occurs by dividing a non-zero number by zero.  You can avoid these by making sure that your denominator `Goal` is never zero.  Assuming you wanted to remove these values you could try:

```
Full_Stats2<-within(Full_Stats, 
              {Minutespergoal<-Minutes_played/Goal })[Goal != 0]
```

Comment: Hi Tim,  thank you very much. I've just tried it with ifelse function and it really works  =========                                                                                                                   
Full_Stats2<-within(Full_Stats, 
                  {Minutespergoal<-ifelse(Goal!=0,Minutes_played/Goal,0) })